# ISCHANGED Workflow

Tags: workflow, formula

We are trying to create a workflow that each time one of the three events below happens it will send an email to a particular user.  Now the workflow works, besides one major flaw.  In order to use ISCHANGED, evaluate rule has to be set to, "created, and everytime it's edited" which is now firing the workflow even if something not included in the formula has changed.  Any suggestions on correcting this?

Formula:

```
Account.RecordTypeId="012A0000000hEaT"&&
ISCHANGED(Email)||
ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId) ||
CONTAINS(Title,"FORMER")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably continually firing because the title contains "FORMER"

Try the following:

```
Account.RecordTypeId="012A0000000hEaT"&& 
(
ISCHANGED(Email) || 
ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId) || 
(ISCHANGED(Title) && CONTAINS(Title,"FORMER"))
)
```

Edit:
See the comment from @DerekF below for additional insight into why you experienced that workflow behavior.

Comment: Deduction supports your conclusion. I think it's worth noting that a significant portion of OP's issue is likely to be that of [precedence of operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm). Your addition of `ISCHANGED(Title)` is important in this context, but I'd argue that the extra parenthesis around the parts of the expression being OR'd together is at least equally as important here (if not more so).

Comment: @DerekF Agreed on all points.

Comment: @DerekF thank you!